# microsoft rdc connection problem in latest version

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, remote-desktop, rdc-manager

I need to connect to a remote windows machine from my mac and i can do so with version 1.0.3 but when I installed the latest version it fails saying my credentials are incorrect. has anyone experienced the same problem / know if there is some preference i need to change ?

Comment: Check RDC preferences. I think there's something about the supported authentication protocols in there -- probably set to a too strict value, and your Windows machine doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to remove the entires from the keychain (using Keychain Access and re-store any saved passwords.  If you're not using saved passwords, then something else is afoot.

[CoRD](http://cord.sourceforge.net) has the same problem.  Users will upgrade then complain to us that "nothing works" any more.  And its just their saved passwords aren't being used any more because we're missing some signed binary guideline somewhere that's causing Keychain to throw a fit.

Comment: your client works fine as well keychain has no reference

Comment: for whatever reason the new version or ms rdc is not compatible with our server so I am now use CoRD